# timidity Hogging CPU, Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, process

On Ubuntu 16.04,`timidity -0s -iAD` is hogging one of my CPU cores. Looking in `pstree`, `systemd` is the parent process. This has been happening when awaking my laptop from sleep. I also cannot kill 15 or kill 9 the process `Operation not permitted`. Happy to post other logs etc if needed.

[can't post image directly, image of htop data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5IU1.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a similar problem with timidity spinning on 14.04.

It worked to do `sudo killall -9 timidity`.  You need the `sudo` because the process is owned by the `timidity` userid.

I see a comment at at http://www.pclinuxos.com/forum/index.php?topic=124239.0 about something like this in KDE after logout, and a fix involving `$HOME/.kde4/shutdown/MidExit` which should say `killall -9 timidity &`

But though I use KDE on 14.04, I don't see a line like that, and I haven't logged out since reboot.

I reported it at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/timidity/+bug/1638341

Comment: I'd accept your answer, but recently upgraded to 16.10 and have not had the issue since.

Comment: @cyniphile Glad to hear it cleared up for you :)  Of course you could still accept this answer just because it resolves the other issue you asked about, by pointing out the need for `sudo`.