# timidity occasionally running amok

Tags: 20.04

Looked at [timidity Hogging CPU, Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/828299/timidity-hogging-cpu-ubuntu-16-04)

Running Ubuntu Studio 20.04.  Occasionally I'll look out there and find timidity running, using up a whole CPU.  I have not found the reason for this...  it does not appear to be in use by any of the apps I am running (and can shut them all down, with timidity still spinning).

I'm looking at the syslog, and I can see:

```
syslog.1:Dec  8 07:14:31 Parker systemd[1]: Starting LSB: start and stop timidity...
syslog.1:Dec  8 07:14:32 Parker timidity[713]:  * Starting TiMidity++ ALSA midi emulation timidity
syslog.1:Dec  8 07:14:32 Parker timidity[713]:    ...done.
syslog.1:Dec  8 07:14:32 Parker systemd[1]: Started LSB: start and stop timidity.
```

That appears to be at boot.  I have not had success in reproducing this.  Most times, I boot up, and check, and it's not running.  Sometimes, it's spinning.  So, perhaps sometimes the "stop timidity" doesn't happen.   Any suggestions on how to track this down?

It's working hard!

```
me@Parker:/var/log$ who -b
         system boot  2020-12-08 07:14
me@Parker:/var/log$ date
Tue 08 Dec 2020 10:58:03 AM EST
me@Parker:/var/log$ ps -o lstart= -p 847
Tue Dec  8 07:14:31 2020
me@Parker:/var/log$ ps -o %cpu,%mem,cmd -p 847
%CPU %MEM CMD
94.7  0.0 /usr/bin/timidity -Os -iAD
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Timidity runs from boot to shutdown by design. (this is part of the reason it is not included in ubuntustudio by default) If it is using excess CPU while not being used perhaps file a bug report against that package. Type ubuntu-bug timidity in a terminal to do this.

As a side note, I have also had trouble with timidity not releasing an audio device and having no sound as well. My solution has generally been to remove the timidity package. Beware that if you did not explicitly install timidity, removing it will probably try to remove other software as well that requires it. So it is best to use a software manager that will tell you what it is removing before it does so. (apt, synaptic, or muon)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, and I've submitted a bug as you suggested. Luckily I can just kill the timidity process.  I occasionally use other tools which need timidity, so I can't dispense with it.  I'll update this as it progresses (or not).  Thanks again!